# Creating MySql log

Tags: mysql

Helllo, My question is the following: using php, is it possible to create a log of all the interactions with the MySQL database which in general can be accessed by phpMyadmin. Is there a specific query or an example that I can look at?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is simple way to capture SQL log. this log called general log. it captures all sql executed by all clients.

to enable general log.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

where is log located?

```
mysql> SHOW variables like '%general_log%';
+------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value              |
+------------------+--------------------+
| general_log      | ON                 |
| general_log_file | /tmp/your_path.log |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

you want change location?

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log_file = 'what you want';
```

to turn off log

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
```

be careful, general log will grow big, after test done, always turn off the log

Comment: Wow, it's great answer. Better than my answer. I will search and study for that also. :)

Comment: @Jerielle to be frankly with, I also learned new skill from you answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use trigger command. First create a log table for the specific table then insert all the trigger outputs there.

Here's the sample:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales_category` (
    `salescatid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `salescatname` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `salescatdesc` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `salescatname` (`salescatname`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `salescatid` (`salescatid`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB



2. Create table for log

CREATE TABLE `category_log` (
    `action` ENUM('CREATE','UPDATE','DELETE') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `salescatid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `salescatname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `salescatdesc` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `id` (`salescatid`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

3. Add triggers

    //FOR ADD

    DELIMITER #
    CREATE TRIGGER ai_category
    AFTER INSERT ON sales_category
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO category_log(action,salescatid,salescatname,salescatdesc)
        VALUES('CREATE',NEW.salescatid,NEW.salescatname,NEW.salescatdesc);
    END;#


    //FOR UPDATE

    DELIMITER #
    CREATE TRIGGER au_category
    AFTER UPDATE ON sales_category
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO category_log(action,salescatid,salescatname,salescatdesc)
        VALUES('UPDATE',NEW.salescatid,NEW.salescatname,NEW.salescatdesc);
    END;#


    //FOR DELETE

    DELIMITER #
    CREATE TRIGGER ad_category
    AFTER DELETE ON sales_category
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO category_log(action,salescatid,salescatname,salescatdesc)
        VALUES('DELETE',OLD.salescatid,OLD.salescatname,OLD.salescatdesc);
    END;#
```

Is this what you are looking for? This is CRUD process but it is done thru SQL commands. If you what to call this I think you should put this in a function.. I am also a beginner so if there's a bug kindly tell me also. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the query log, put this in `/etc/my.cnf` in the `[mysqld]` section

```
log   = /path/to/query.log
```

remember that this logfile can grow very big on a busy server

update:

as of mysql 5.1.12 you should use

```
general_log=1
```

with mysql 5.1.29, the log option is deprecated. to specify the logfile use

```
general_log_file=/path/to/query.log
```

instead. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html

Enable Query logging on the database (Note that the string 'table' should be put literally and not substituted by any table name)

```
SET global general_log = 1;
SET global log_output = 'table';
```

View the log

```
select * from mysql.general_log
```

Disable Query logging on the database

```
SET global general_log = 0;
```

Refer: http://www.jovicailic.org/2012/07/how-to-enable-general-query-log-in-mysql-under-linux/